# the close button does not work

Tags: javascript, html

I have put my close button in div but it didn't work? I should keep the display:none;but when I remove display it works!

```
 function myFun() {
    var button  = document.getElementById("myBtn");
    button.onclick = function() {
    var div = document.getElementById('title');
    if (div.style.display !== 'none') {
        div.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        div.style.display = 'block';
    }



};
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="title" style=" display:none; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; position:absolute; top: 50px; right: 16px; padding: 30px; z-index:10; width:290px; height:500px; box-sizing: border-box;  background-color:#fcfcfc ; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); text-align:center; float:center;"><input type="button" id="myBtn" onclick="myFun()" value="close" style= "bottom: 2px; right: 60px; margin: 1px 200px;"></div>
```

Comment: What should close button do ?

Comment: @Rayon I guess, button should call `myFun()` :D

Comment: I've understood. So, `visibility:hidden` makes button invisible.

Comment: The `title` `div` is hidden `visibility:hidden;` maybe the button works but you don't see the effects because of that.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `visibility:hidden`.
Thus you will get what you want, because div will appear with your button without `visibility:hidden`.

Comment: Thanx R, actually I need that visibility:hidden; its a search table that appearing after search complete

Comment: @adonia You are welcome. Please accept one of the answers if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Its working Fine Bro. You just need to remove   <strike>visibility:hidden</strike>

```js
function myFun() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myBtn").value;
    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = x;
    alert(x);
}
```

```css
#title{
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    height: 500px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50px;
    width: 290px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="title">
 <input type="button" id="myBtn" onclick="myFun()" value="close"></div>
 </body>
```

Comment: Thanx bro, actually I need that  visibility:hidden; its a search table that appearing after search complete.